# Django dumpdata for an entire database

Tags: django

I'm getting this error message when I try to dump data from my legacy database (managed=False) when using django.

> python manage.py dumpdata --database legacy_db
>
> CommandError: Unable to serialize database: (1146, "Table 'legacy_db.django_content_type' doesn't exist")

I do need the legacy data to be placed in fixtures for test purposes. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: looks like you have to create that table in there: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: The legacy_db already exists and I can read from when running the server. I'm using django API framework btw. I just can't dump the legacy database.

Comment: read it again - you have to create the **table** `django_content_type` in there.